# How to set which way suggestions pop up in material ui text field

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material ui to make a React front-end for my web application. I have 2 text fields in a React component and for the upper, suggestions pop up downwards. For the bottom one suggestions suddenly pop up upwards. I don't want that, I like them downwards. Is there a way to set this?

Code:

```
<TextField className="textfield" label="I offer..." id="wants"></TextField><br />
<TextField className="textfield" label="In trade for..." id="wants"></TextField><br />
```

Screenshots:
[image: Text field 1]
[image: Text field 2]

Comment: The menu items normally open downwards, but if the select is is close to the bottom of the window then the menu items will open upwards. How close is your second select to the bottom of your window?

Comment: @Tejogol It is indeed pretty close. Isn't there a way to override this though?

Comment: Are you using the Autocomplete component or manually creating the Menu? TextField doesn't have suggestions by default. Can you include the code for how you're creating the suggestion menu?